# Licencias para desplegar aplicacion de WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola soy nuevo en el mundo de softwares y tengo la duda de que si ya tengo mi aplicacion en wpf echa que necesito para desplegarla en el tema de las licencias, tengo que adquirir alguna licencia de c#? y tambien estoy usando caliburn micro, cambiaria algo en el mismo tema de las licencias?, o simplemente soy libre para desplegar la aplicacion por mi cuenta, actualmente la desarrolle con la version comunity de vs. Soy nuevo en este mundo no sean duros conmigo :)

PD: Si deseo vender la aplicacion

Comment: Para el tema de licencia honestamente te recomiendo mejor lo consultes con quien te provee el software que usas

Comment: Una vez que descargas cada programa que usas viene una licencia que te indica que puedes y que no puedes hacer con el

Comment: too depende de si vasa vender o no tu soft...

Comment: Tienes que fijarte en 2 cosas, primero en tu IDE, en tu caso sería VS Community, esa versión tiene sus limitaciones pero SI PUEDES vender siempre que seas un desarrollador INDIVIDUAL, osea, no puedes hacer negocios con tu app si eres una empresa, ves? y segundo, ver si estás usando algún plugin o librería que vaya incluida en tu software, un DLL por ejemplo que esté bajo una licencia prohibitiva, o también si usas un recurso que el autor prohíba venderlo o distribuirlo, un fuente tipográfica por ejemplo, un audio, una imagen, un video, un logo, etc